# How to execute a Stored Procedure on the results of a SQL Server CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a CTE which returns DISTINCT ID's. I want to execute a scalar function on each of the Id's returned.

```
WITH cte (reqID) as 

(SELECT DISTINCT pol.ReqID FROM 
LOG_PackingListItems pli
JOIN
v_PO_LN              pol on pol.PO_ID  = pli.PoId
WHERE  
pli.PackingListHeaderID = 1)


EXEC dbo.spUpdateLOG_ReqCompleteCheck  reqID -- Error "Incorrect Syntax near EXEC"
```

The EXEC line is what I want to make work but I get a syntax error. Not sure if what I want to do is possible or if I do in fact have a syntax error. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I'm adding the code for the Stored Procedure since I am now using a Table-Valued Parameter as suggested by realnumber3012

**EDIT:**
I have changed my CTE code so it populates a Table-Type as realnumber has suggested. I now get an error when executing spUpdateLOG_ReqCompleteCheck "Subquery returns more than one value."

```
DECLARE @ReqIdTVP as ReqIdType;
DELETE FROM @ReqIDTVP;
with cte (reqID) as 
(select distinct pol.ReqID from 
 LOG_PackingListItems pli
 join
 v_PO_LN    pol on pol.PO_ID  = pli.PoId
 where 
  pli.PackingListHeaderID = @PackingListHeaderID)

INSERT INTO @ReqIdTVP 
SELECT * FROM cte

EXEC dbo.spUpdateLOG_ReqCompleteCheck @ReqIdTVP
```

Sproc code :

```
Alter PROCEDURE spUpdateLOG_ReqCompleteCheck

(@ReqIdTVP ReqIdType READONLY )  

AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @TotalOrd int
DECLARE @TotalRx int
DECLARE @ReqID char(8)  

SET @ReqID = (SELECT  ReqID FROM @ReqIdTVP)

SET @TotalOrd = (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ORD_QTY),0)
            FROM        dbo.v_PoLnNonFreight  l
            WHERE l.ReqID = @reqID)


SET @TotalRx = (SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(TotalRxSite),0)
            FROM        dbo.v_PoLnNonFreight  l
            WHERE l.ReqID = @reqID)


IF @TotalRx >=  @TotalOrd
 BEGIN
  DECLARE @curDate datetime
  SET @CurDate = ISNULL(@CurDate,GetDate()) 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE LOG_ReqHeader   
  SET 
ReqCompleteDate   = @curDate,
ReqStatus = 'Complete'

  WHERE ReqID = @ReqID  
 END
END
```

Comment: version of SQL SERVER?

Comment: Sorry, didn't think about needing to provide that, 2008 R2

Comment: Can you change the title? It's very misleading. You aren't issuing a scalar function on the results you are trying call a stored procedure for each row. That's a huge difference. If you were wanting to apply a scalar function then you'd use the CROSS APPLY operator......

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the only thing your stored proc does is to update a logging table: (it only changes *state* via this statement and doesn't return anything????

```
UPDATE LOG_ReqHeader   
  SET 
ReqCompleteDate   = @curDate,
ReqStatus = 'Complete'

  WHERE ReqID = @ReqID
```

How about splitting the logic out and write a function (inline if possible that will evaluate the condition you are looking for (didn't really understand what you are doind there) -- run the function on the results of the CTE (wrapping it in another CTE if you want) with the CROSS APPLY OPERATOR.

You'd end up with a result set that looks like [ReqId], [UpdateLog] (where updateLog is a BIT)

Then simply do a set based upadete JOINING to the results:

```
UPDATE l SET
    ReqCompleteDate   = @curDate,
    ReqStatus = 'Complete'
FROM
    LOG_ReqHeader AS l
    JOIN <CTE> AS c ON c.[ReqID] = l.[ReqID]
WHERE
    c.[UpdateLog] = 0x1
```

Does this make any sense?

Comment: I have a requisitions app (part of the Logisitics department, hence the LOG_ preface to the ReqHeader table). I have a trigger which runs when requisition line items are marked as received as part of Packing List,(possible only partial requisition receipt). The CTE returns the ReqID(s) I need to evaluate to see if I should update the LOG_ReqHeader table Complete Date once all ordered items have been recieved for each requisition in Packing List. spUpdateLOG_ReqCompleteCheck needs to loop through ReqID's but that's where I'm getting the subquery returns more than 1 value. Hope this is clear.